# How to write different code for windows and windows phone apps in windows 10 apps

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I created a new windows 10 app, In solution file common main page is created for windows and windows phone, now i want display button only in windows app, not in windows phone app, is it possible please help me..

```
<Grid x:Name="menu">
  <Button x:name="btn1" content="click"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to display this button only in window , not for Phone app, how to disable in windows phone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can do this.
1) Using device-family either in code behind or as another xaml
See this [tutorial](http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/) you will get the idea.
2) Now if you want you can also use Viewstates along with Adaptive triggers which is simple but these will work even when desktop app is resized to avoid that you will have to create device specific triggers. check out [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers)

Comment: but how to write code for created mainpages for windows and phone only created xaml file..

Comment: Well thats where UWP shines. If the app is being run in phone it will access the DeviceFamily-Type family folder and load those xamls instead of desktop one as long as their names are same.

Comment: According to your question you just wanted to make button invisible. So for that instead of adding complete blank page you are required to add just the xaml file in device folder. Now if you want to make changes to code also make use of second method as answered and in C# code check the device family and execute the required code